# DirectX FVF(Flexible Vertex Format ) equivalent in OpenGL/Vulkan?

Tags: opengl, vulkan, directx

Is there any directX FVF(Flexible Vertex Format ) equivalent in OpenGL/Vulkan.

Answer (score 2):

Vulkan uses vertex attributes. Here is an example:

```
const VkVertexInputAttributeDescription vertexAttributes[] = {
    // location, binding, format, offset
    { 0,        0,      VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT,     0 }, // inPosition
    { 1,        0,      VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT,     12 }, // inNormal
    { 2,        0,      VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT,      24 }, // inTangent
    { 3,        0,      VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT,        40 }, // inTexCoord
};
```

And a description:

```
const VkVertexInputBindingDescription vertexInputBindings[] = { 
    // binding, stride, inputRate
    { 0, 48, VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX} 
};
```